# asp.net page methods returning undefined

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-ajax

I am trying to use page methods in my asp.net page.  I have enable page methods set to true on the script manager, the webmethod attribute defined on the method, the function is public static string, I know the function works because when I run it from my code behind it generates the expected result, but when I call it via page method in my result function the result is always alerted as undefined.  If I use fiddler it doesn't even look like there is additional traffic or a new request created.  I'm running the site on port 82 if that makes a difference.  I'm at a loss here. Can someone give me some pointers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your PagesMethods call, remove the parentheses from the callback and error functions:

```
PageMethods.getAdCodeInfo(value, onSuccess, onError)
```

`onSuccess` and `onError` are basically variables that point to the functions.  So you don't need parentheses for variable names.

Answer (score 0):

OK, stupid me. Here is some code.

```
 function getName()
 {
    var ddlAdCodes=$get('<%=ddlAdCodes.ClientID %>');
    var value=ddlAdCodes.options[ddlAdCodes.selectedIndex].value;
    //alert(value);
    PageMethods.getAdCodeInfo(value,onSuccess(),onError());
 }

 function onSuccess(result)
 {
    alert(result);
 }

 function onError(error)
 {
    alert("error "+error);
 }
```

Comment: Next time hit the "Code Sample" button (101010) to format it nicely and make it easier to read.